# IO#lines is deprecated in Ruby 2.0; how do I iterate line by line?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

My Ruby 1.9.3 code opens a file and checks each line for the presence of a certain string:

```
if File.open('Gemfile').lines.any?{|line| line.include?('pg')}
  puts "found 'pg'"
end
```

Ruby 2.0.0 gives me a warning:

> warning: IO#lines is deprecated; use #each_line instead

What's the most efficient way to implement this in Ruby 2.0.0?

Comment: `lines` quickly leads to code that isn't scalable, because it encourages loading an entire file into memory, prior to iterating. While today's hosts have many GB of RAM, that doesn't give us a good reason to try to load that many GB of text into memory at once. Instead, using [`foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) or [`each_line`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-each_line) conserves the memory, resulting in very close to the same execution speed, without the excessive RAM use.

Comment: What happens if a line doesn't contain the string? The fastest way to do this check is to use `grep` if you're running on Linux or Mac OS. It's highly optimized for fast searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ruby 2.0 `IO#each_line` can return an enumerator. So replacing `lines` by `each_line` or simply by `each` should work exactly as your current code.

```
if File.open('Gemfile').each {|line| line.include?('pg')}
  puts "found 'pg'"
end
```